# TestNG runs no test from console

Tags: java, netbeans, testng

I installed NetBeans 8.0.1 on my computer and used it to create a test suite :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="testing">
    <test name="suite">
        <packages>
            <package name="myPackage.tests"/>
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

In myPackage.tests there is a test class, a very simple one :

```
[package, imports]

public class Tests001 {

public Tests001 () {
}

@Test
public void Fail() {
    assertFalse(true);
}
```

In NetBeans, I launched the test by right-clicking the.xml file and selecting 'test file'. Everything works perfectly - or rather, it correctly fails - intended result for now.

But I need to launch it from console, so I run :

```
> java org.testng.TestNG testing.xml
```

And get :

```
===============================================
testing
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

No test is run. I can't find out why : test class and methods are public ; java is configured correctly (JDK 1.8.0_25) and I set CLASSPATH to

```
C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.1\platform\modules\ext\testng-6.8.1-dist.jar
```

I must have forgotten something...
Or is there a way, from console, to ask NetBeans to proceed to test ?

Comment: Can you really run a testing.xml file instead of testng.xml?

Comment: I don't understand your question : testing.xml is the suite file's name. I should have chosen a clearer name.

Comment: Dear Sir, that is the default xml file used for running testng suites. I have never used a different name or seen anyone else so it, that's what my query is.

Comment: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml

Comment: I see. I think you can give any name you want to your .xml suite file. For instance, in part 4 of the page whose link you gave, it gives an exemple : "java org.testng.TestNG testng1.xml [testng2.xml testng3.xml ...]"

Comment: @AndréLecointre Have you added the compiled classes to CLASSPATH? TestNG will try to load all test cases in the package. If nothing is found, there is 0 test cases. NetBeans may have done this for you when it is used.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. How do you think is the best way to do it ? I defined the path to TestNG in my classpath and do not wish it to be erased with 'java -cp'.

Comment: @AndréLecointre From TestNG document, the `testng.test.classpath` property is designed for this purpose. However, I have a try and it doesn't work. `java -Dtestng.test.classpath="c:/build;c:/java/classes;" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
`

Comment: @AndréLecointre Try `java -cp %classpath%;<compiled classes dir>`.

Comment: Thanks again for your suggestions ! Yhe last one doesn't work : testng is launched, but still runs 0 test. EDIT : the other suggestion doesn't work either  :/

Comment: @AndréLecointre You couldn't make it work via `java -cp`? If so, would you please check your command to make sure the test classes can be found?

Comment: @longhua Well I used `java -cp %classpath%;. org.testng.TestNG testing.xml` since xml and class files are in the same directory. It didn't work. `%classpath%` gives the right path to my testng library. I even tried to puth the "." in the classpath variable - same result. TestNG is correctly run, but my class is ignored.

Comment: @AndréLecointre Would you please show the file structure? Are your classes in the folder myPackage\tests?

Comment: Everything was built using NetBeans 8, so it gives long folder structures  :/  The source files are in `Project/test/unit/src/org/company/package/tests/` - this is where you'll find the .xml and the test class. Once built, result files are in `Project/build/test/unit/classes/org/company/package/tests/`. Again, thanks for helping !   :)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the suite.xml file needs this structure:

```
<suite name="mySuite" allow-return-values="true" parallel="tests"
       verbose="1" thread-count="2">

    <test name="TestStuff">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="Smoke.mytests"/>
            </run>
        </groups>
        <packages>
            <package name="com.myco.mytests"/>
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```